# How to display a value from a different object, from a lookup field?

Tags: custom-field, product, cross-object

I'm new to Salesforce and I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction...

Right now, I have a product called **Session**, and another product called **Program**. Let's say each record in **Program** has a `Name` and a `Duration`.

In **Session**, I have set up a lookup field that allows me to point to the name of a particular record in **Program**.

What I'm looking to do is to get the `Duration` as well, read-only. I'm looking into cross-object fields, but I can't put my finger on what I should do.

Could you please help? Any piece of advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On Session object, create a formula field. Then in the formula, select the parent object's Duration field. You should be good.

Comment: OMG that was so simple and straightforward! THANK YOU!